# Iptables to block ssl3/tls on network

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, routing, iptables

I tried to block application data packets on my computer using the rule

```sh
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp \! -f --dport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m u32 --u32 "0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 0 & 0xFF000000=0x17000000" -j DROP
```

This allows handshakes to go through for websites but blocks application packets.

While this works, I would like some websites to be able to connect to the net, so I add another rule

```sh
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp \! -f --dport 443 -s 69.171.230.68 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m u32 --u32 "0>>22&0x3C@ 12>>26&0x3C@ 0 & 0xFF000000=0x17000000" -j ACCEPT
```

However, when I try to connect to that particular ipaddress this does not work. (Packets are blocked and do not show up in wireshark)

Would you know a reason why this happens and help me debug this functionality !!

Note: To understand the above rules, you may have to read this [blog](https://blog.g3rt.nl/take-down-sslv3-using-iptables.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `-s 69.171.230.68` with `-d 69.171.230.68`, because you are in the output chain, and the website is the destination.